# Hide and show button are not showing up using datatable api

Tags: jquery, html, css, datatable

I am using this example for reference:
https://datatables.net/extensions/responsive/examples/styling/bootstrap.html

but the button is not showing up. I have used tried many examples of the datatable API but not able to get the + - button.

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8"
pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form" prefix="form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="spring" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
/> 

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" 
/> 

<link rel="stylesheet"
href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.m
in.css" /> 




<meta name="description" content="Child Rows">
<title>ABC</title>
<style>

</style>


</head>
<body>



<div class="table-responsive">
    <table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered dt-
responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="60%" align=center>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
            <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
            <td>8196</td>
            <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>6373</td>
            <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 </body>
 <!-- /.modal -->

 <script type="text/javascript" src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js">
 </script>
 <script type="text/javascript"
 src="//cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

 <script type="text/javascript"  
 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/dataTables.bootstrap.min.js">
  </script>

 <script 

 src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTa
 bles.responsive.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript"
src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/responsive.bootstrap.min
.js"></script>

 <script>

 $(document).ready(function() {

$('#example').DataTable();
} );

    </script>

</html>
```

I have included all the required Javascript library and css for this example but still the same issue[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sFLjJ.png)

All other functionality for pagination is working fine but unable to show button for child row.
Could someone please suggest?

Comment: + button comes with the responsive design. Did you refer responsive plugins?

Comment: Try giving a `width: 100px;` to your datatable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check below, Add jquery before other js files, make sure to add `table-responsive` class inside your table tag, Make sure to use external files correct order and finally plus button comes with smaller display due to responsive feature.

```js
$('#example').DataTable();
```

```html
<!--External Js-->
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/js/dataTables.responsive.min.js"></script>

<!--External CSS-->
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.16/css/dataTables.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.2.1/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>


<!--Table-->
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-responsive table-bordered dt-
responsive nowrap" cellspacing="0" width="60%" align=center>
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>First name</th>
            <th>Last name</th>
            <th>Position</th>
            <th>Office</th>
            <th>Age</th>
            <th>Start date</th>
            <th>Salary</th>
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>Tiger</td>
            <td>Nixon</td>
            <td>System Architect</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>61</td>
            <td>2011/04/25</td>
            <td>$320,800</td>
            <td>5421</td>
            <td>t.nixon@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>


        <tr>
            <td>Lael</td>
            <td>Greer</td>
            <td>Systems Administrator</td>
            <td>London</td>
            <td>21</td>
            <td>2009/02/27</td>
            <td>$103,500</td>
            <td>6733</td>
            <td>l.greer@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Jonas</td>
            <td>Alexander</td>
            <td>Developer</td>
            <td>San Francisco</td>
            <td>30</td>
            <td>2010/07/14</td>
            <td>$86,500</td>
            <td>8196</td>
            <td>j.alexander@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Shad</td>
            <td>Decker</td>
            <td>Regional Director</td>
            <td>Edinburgh</td>
            <td>51</td>
            <td>2008/11/13</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>6373</td>
            <td>s.decker@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Michael</td>
            <td>Bruce</td>
            <td>Javascript Developer</td>
            <td>Singapore</td>
            <td>29</td>
            <td>2011/06/27</td>
            <td>$183,000</td>
            <td>5384</td>
            <td>m.bruce@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Donna</td>
            <td>Snider</td>
            <td>Customer Support</td>
            <td>New York</td>
            <td>27</td>
            <td>2011/01/25</td>
            <td>$112,000</td>
            <td>4226</td>
            <td>d.snider@datatables.net</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
 </table>
```

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. I tried as you mentioned, but still its is not working. Do I need any other Javascript library

Comment: Can you copy exact code to one of new file and test

Comment: It seems my responsive.bootstrap.min.js is not loading when i inspect element.

Comment: Hi, I tried adding jquery before other js files, but then pagination also fails.

Comment: Hi, It starts working now, but when I try to minimize the window, then only the button appears. when I maximize it disappears, seems some page responsive issue.

Comment: Hi, Just one other query : eg.                                                                                 
            <th>Extn.</th>
            <th>E-mail</th> displays as other two rows when we click on + sign. I want it to display both <td> in single row. How is it possible?